# Using Terraform, how would I create a AWS Kubernetes cluster with Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am looking for a recipe using Terraform to create a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using Fargate.  I cannot find any end-to-end documentation to do this.

I am using SSO, and so terraform needs to use my AWS credentials to do this.

No example I can find addresses using AWS credentials and Fargate.

If anyone has done this and has a recipe for all of the above, please share.

Comment: If you need an end-to-end documented solution, the answer is eksctl. I personally use terraform for eks but it is considerably more work and time figuring stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use popular module for that 
[terraform-aws-eks](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks). It supports Fargate EKS as well. Since its open sourced, you can also have a look at exactly how to create such clusters if you want to fork and customize the module, or create your own scratch.

Example use for Fargate EKS from its docs:

```
module "eks" {
  source          = "../.."
  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.17"
  subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
    GithubRepo  = "terraform-aws-eks"
    GithubOrg   = "terraform-aws-modules"
  }

  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  fargate_profiles = {
    example = {
      namespace = "default"

      # Kubernetes labels for selection
      # labels = {
      #   Environment = "test"
      #   GithubRepo  = "terraform-aws-eks"
      #   GithubOrg   = "terraform-aws-modules"
      # }

      # using specific subnets instead of all the ones configured in eks
      # subnets = ["subnet-0ca3e3d1234a56c78"]

      tags = {
        Owner = "test"
      }
    }
  }

  map_roles    = var.map_roles
  map_users    = var.map_users
  map_accounts = var.map_accounts
}
```

Comment: This does not work.  Can you please show exactly how you are using what is above? Thank you.

Comment: @user10664542 I already provided the link to github which has all the code and its examples. There is no better example that what's on github.